# get value of a uncertain variable in Julia JuMPeR

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, robust

I want to solve a robust optimization problem with Julia JuMPeR. Is there any way to get the values of uncertain variables in the solution in Julia JuMPeR? I am using Julia v1.5.

Comment: Hello, an example minimal working source code would surely help to get answer to that question.

Comment: I'll also note that JuMPeR is unmaintained at this point. (The last commit was >3 years ago.)